# Convergence of integral $\int_{0.5}^{1} \log(|\log(t)|)\ ^ 7\,\mathrm{d}t $

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence

Does this integral converge ? 
$$\int_{0.5}^{1} \log(|\log(t)|)\ ^ 7 \,\mathrm{d}t $$

I have tried to compare this integral to 
$$\int_{0.5}^{1} \dfrac{1 }{\sqrt{x-1}} \,\mathrm{d}t $$
but couldn't find the limit of the division when x goes to 1 from left.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

$\int\limits_{0.5}^1(\ln|\ln t|)^7 dt=-\int\limits_{1/\ln2}^\infty(\ln t)^7 e^{-\frac{1}{t}}\frac{dt}{t^2}$

$0<\int\limits_{1/\ln2}^\infty(\ln t)^7 e^{-\frac{1}{t}}\frac{dt}{t^2}\le \frac{1}{2}\int\limits_{1/\ln2}^\infty(\ln t)^7\frac{dt}{t^2}=
\frac{7!\ln 2}{2}\sum\limits_{k=0}^7 \frac{(\ln\frac{1}{\ln2})^k}{k!}<\infty$

based on the formular for $\int\frac{(\ln x)^n}{x^m}$, $m\ne 1$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{(\ln x)^a}{x^b}=0$ for $b>0$.

Answer (score 0):

By the substitutions $t=\frac{1}{u}$, $u=e^v$
$$I=\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}\log\left(\left|\log t\right|\right)\,dt = \int_{1}^{2}\frac{\log\log u}{u^2}\,du = \int_{0}^{\log 2}\frac{\log v}{e^v}\,dv$$
and both $\log v$ and $e^v$ belong to $L^2(0,\log 2)$, so:
$$ \left| I \right| \leq \sqrt{\int_{0}^{\log 2}\frac{dv}{e^{2v}}\int_{0}^{\log 2}\log^2 v\,dv}<\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} $$
by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.